# How to install PHP for local development on a daily use Ubuntu machine, only running when called?

Tags: ubuntu, php, development

I did this years ago, but at this point I don't recall how anymore, so I know it's doable, and I've yet to find good documentation in any other way than it's possible.

I'm looking for how to install PHP (on a desktop ubuntu environment) to where PHP isn't a constantly running service running webpages but only launches when explicitly called, is easy to close when done, is accessible to IDEs, and includes break-point functionality.

Comment: Sounds like completely normal PHP installation to me

Comment: I haven't seen one yet that out of the box doesn't try to set itself up as a start-on-startup service, or set up apache/nginx constantly running in the background, etc. Then again, as I said, it's been a few years (reinstalling because my computer died), maybe it's better now, and they've seperated the apts for server vs local development, if that's what you're implying?

Comment: PHP has always been a standalone tool and is delivered as independent packages on Debian and Ubuntu. It can be coupled to a server in a few ways, some of which involve having a pool of processes running, but that's how servers work. PHP also has its built in development server which can be started on demand. Frameworks can provide their solutions too, eg. Symfony has a custom optimized server, also launched on demand. Installing PHP alone doesn't cause anything to run in background.

Comment: so just `sudo apt install php` will do exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: Could you elaborate whether you use PHP in combination with a server like Apache or Ngix? Because PHP itself is not the problem here but probably apache/ngix is what you refer to as "constantly running service". So then the trick would be to disable the service (e.g. `sudo systemctl disable apache2 && sudo systemctl stop apache2` ) and enable it when needed (sudo systemctl enable apache2 && sudo systemctl start apache2`)

Comment: That's close to what I'm talking about (and yes, it was apache2 at the time), but Apache started when PHP was invoked, and stopped when whatever command it was stopped running. The result was running PHP scripts from command lines & IDEs would still produce viable output without having to bog down the day-to-day running of the host machine otherwise. Further, it was fully capable of running with breakpoints. It was years ago I ran with this setup, so I was hoping it was standard available somewhere as launch/install options, but haven't found it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't if it includes break-pint functionality, but after install, you can try the [PHP Built-In Web Server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```